# How to set values of subclassed UIView properties when loading subclass from a xib

Tags: objective-c, uiview, interface-builder, subclass, xib

I have a subclassed UIView called BannerHeaderView, and designed the way I want it layed out in an xib. I have set the xib class to BannerHeaderView. I have a UILabel and a UIImageView which I have connected in IB.

The problem is that when I go to set the values of these subViews after initialising my BannerHeaderView in a ViewController, the label and image view are null. I have tried setting them in init also.

Code for BannerHeaderView.h:

```
@interface BannerHeaderView : UIView
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *bannerImage;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *headerLabel;

-(void)setTitle:(NSString *)title;
-(void)setImageFile:(PFFile *)imageFile;

@end
```

Code for BannerHeaderView.m:

```
@implementation BannerHeaderView
@synthesize headerLabel, bannerImage;

-(id)init{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self customInit];
    }
    return self;
}

-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self customInit];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)customInit{
    UIView *contentView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"BannerHeaderView"
                                   owner:self
                                 options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    [self addSubview:contentView];
    contentView.frame = self.bounds;
}

-(void)setTitle:(NSString *)title{
    NSLog(@"HEADER = %@", headerLabel);
    headerLabel.text = title;
}
```

And I am creating the BannerHeaderImage in my ViewController like so:

```
bannerHeader = [[BannerHeaderView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, bannerHeight + segmentedHeaderHeight)];
[bannerHeader setTitle:@"I AM THE NEW TITLE"];
```

The log tells me that the headerLabel is null.

Questions:

How do I set the values of these subviews?
Should I just design the layout of this programatically?

Thanks for your time.

P.S. I have spent hours researching this and I can't find a solution. I did find similar questions on SO but none with suitable answers to enable me to solve my problem...

Comment: add screenshot of 'BannerHeaderView' xib. who is file owner in your xib and have you connect the file owner view property?

Comment: Thanks @Bilal Ashwins answer helped me to solve the problem. (I think you were probably thinking of the same solution).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please set the class BannerHeaderView to File's Owner like this

[image: File owner]

Comment: Thanks, the problem was that I had not set the custom class of the file owner, but also that I had not connected the outlets for the image view and the label in the Connections Inspector for the file owner. When adding the subviews to the xib, I just clicked and dragged them into the header file for BannerHeaderView. I was not aware that I had to set the custom class, and connect the outlets for the file owner as will as the View itself.

Comment: Glad, it helps you!